# React js simple scroll animation

Tags: jquery, reactjs, animation, scroll

I am looking for the simple scroll animation in **React.js**
I have code in **jquery** like below

```
$(elem).stop().animate({
scrollTop: 500}, '500', 'swing')
```

I am looking something similar in React.js

Answer (score 0):

React and jQuery are entirely different things and one is not meant to be a replacement for the functionality of the other. There's no equivalent to jQuery's animate in React.

Either use jQuery as you already are on top of React (although alternative DOM manipulation when using React is probably not a very good idea) or do it with vanilla JS `scrollTop` and CSS animations.

[MDN article on vanilla JS scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)

[Animate.css may be good for more complex CSS animations like swing](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)